Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them
I have a query in my PHP application as follows...
UPDATE
users
SET
is_selected =
CASE WHEN
mrn_id IN (111028,117876,117877,117878,117879)
THEN
1
ELSE
0
END
WHERE
status_id = 396

In the above query the mrn_id IN have around 9000 values like the ones i mentioned in the above example.
and the error am getting...
[DatabaseException] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them.

As per documentation of SQL server the error should come only when this count exceeds 65000+ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-8632-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16
How come am getting this error ? how to debug this ? any setting of mssql i need to update ?
NOTE: The error is happening only when this query runs from PHP script. when i run this query from SQL management studio, it is running absolutely fine.

How many total rows in the table that match  status_id = 396?  You ARE updating all that have status_id = 396 here

Tried just separating it out to two updates. So instead of doing the case in the update, you check if it needs a 1 in the where condition? Then another for the inverse.

Or dump the list of ids into a temporary table and just select from that?

The error is probably because you have 9k IN values. Use a table valued parameter or openjson or anything else but building one giant IN (...) condition. As they saying goes, when you start to wonder what the limits are, you're doing something wrong

"the error should come only when this count exceeds 65000+" No, the documentation states thousands can cause it: "Explicitly including an extremely large number of values (many thousands of values separated by commas) within the parentheses, in an IN clause can consume resources and return errors 8623 or 8632." 9,000 values is many thousands. The most values you can put in an IN is 65,535, but that doesn't mean you can't hit a resource limit before then.

@MarkSchultheiss the table rows count comes around 9000 only

What is SQL Server version?

Here is my 5 second not super well thought out and not tested option here to use a join instead.
DECLARE @IDS AS TABLE(
    mrnId INT
)
INSERT INTO @IDS
VALUES(111028),(117876),(117877),(117878),(117879);

UPDATE u
SET is_selected = IIF(U.mrn_id IS NULL, 0, 1)
FROM users AS U
LEFT OUTER JOIN @IDS AS I ON U.mrn_id = I.mrnId
WHERE
    U.status_id = 396;


Not coincidentally, this is what really happens under the hood when you send table-valued parameters from the server.

Thanks @mark unfortunately this section of code is being rendered within a framework and it is difficult to modify to use the above suggession.
NOTE: The error is happening only when this query runs from PHP script. when i run this query from SQL management studio, it is running absolutely fine.

SO perhaps this is a PHP issue not related specifically to the query but caused by something we do not know.

It is best to create a temporary table and (in parts) add your large list to this table and apply it in the query.
Or, perhaps you should create a permanent table and keep it up to date, as well as create a clustered index for it.
However, if this is a one-time procedure, or it is not possible to create a table (temporary or permanent), look at the solution option.
You can divide large IN list to parts (part1, part2 ...).
Then run 2 or more UPDATE queries, each individual of them does not exceed limit.
1.First
UPDATE users
SET is_selected =
   CASE WHEN mrn_id IN (...part1 ...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE status_id = 396

All rows except IN(part1) updated to is_selected=1 and all other is_selected=0 .
2.Second
UPDATE users
SET is_selected =
   CASE WHEN mrn_id IN (...part2 ...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE status_id = 396 and is_selected=0

We add condition is_selected=0, so rows, updated as is_selected=1 in first query, not updated in second.
3.Next
UPDATE users
SET is_selected =
   CASE WHEN mrn_id IN (...partN ...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE status_id = 396 and is_selected=0

